# SP2013 retrieving localized term Path (term.getPath(lcid))

Tags: localization, term

I'm on SP2013 on prem, using JSOM trying to retrieved localized version of term's path:

```
function getTranslation(refinerguid, language, termstorename, success, error){

    initTax(termstorename);         
    var found_term = termStore.getTerm(refinerguid);

    context.load(found_term);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            if(found_term){
            // success(found_term.get_pathOfTerm());  
              success(found_term.getPath(language).get_value());                                  
            }else{
              error("No translations found for " + refinerguid);
            }
        }, 
        function(){
          error("Translation Failed: "+ refinerguid.toString()+ " " + language.toString());
        }
    );
}
```

get_pathOfTerm() does return path in Default language, however getPath(lcid), supposed to return localized version, returns "0".

Was anybody able to figure this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect we need to explicitly load the `Name` and `Labels`

```
context.load(found_term,'Include(Name,Labels)');
```

Comment: Thank you for an idea, tried, did not help, was getting js error, without "include" it runs fine but returns "0". 
I can use term.get_pathOfTerm() to get full path but only in default language,

Comment: According to MS
[SP.Taxonomy.Term.getPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312557.aspx) should return localized version...